# Angular 1.6 with typescript 2.4, gulp to webpack transition

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

I think I am having a typing issue. I have an angular 1.6 project currently being built using gulp and company wants to switch to webpack 3. I think I am close to getting project to build but having a typing issue where my backed.d.ts file full of our types and api calls are not being recognized I think in webpack or with compiling the .ts files, its hard to tell which.

here is my webpack.config.js

```js
    module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'vendor': './source/vendor.ts',
        'main': './source/index.ts'
    },
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/webpack-build'),
        chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: Infinity,
        }),
        new WebpackMd5Hash(),
        new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin({
            name: 'webpackManifest'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './source/index.html',
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('pack.[contenthash].css')
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        modules: ['source', 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.d.ts', '.js', '.json']
    },
    module: {
        noParse: [
               /aws-sdk/
        ],
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts/,
                include: [
                    __dirname
                ],
                exclude: [
                    '/react/',
                    '/tests/',
                    '/compiled/'
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'ng-annotate-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                  test: /\.js$/,
                  include: [
                      '/node_modules/'
                  ],
                  use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json/,
                use: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and my tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
},
"files": [
    "../typings/tsd.d.ts",
    "./source/swagger/backend.d.ts"
]
```

}

In the vendor.ts is a single import 'backend' which should be importing the types and all from backend.d.ts for the build to use the types for the angular code. Instead here are some of the errors I get below along with many more.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/index.ts:1715:113 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'SessionCookieService'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/index.ts:1716:37 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'ApplicationSettingsService'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/index.ts:1717:17 
    TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'angular'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/index.ts:1717:51 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'States'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/index.ts:1718:24 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'SearchService'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/swagger/backend.d.ts:5:9 
    TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'ng'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/swagger/backend.d.ts:10:9 
    TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'ng'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/swagger/backend.d.ts:15:9 
    TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'ng'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/swagger/backend.d.ts:21:9 
    TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'ng'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/swagger/backend.d.ts:29:9 
    TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'ng'.

**UPDATE:**
npm i @types/angular --save got rid of the cannot find namespace 'ng' error but now there is 
ERROR in [at-loader] ./source/index.ts:1717:25 
    TS2694: Namespace 'angular' has no exported member 'ui'.

and my custom types are not being recognized since I think I am not importing the files correctly but too many incorrect ways to import things now.